# Database connection issue through docker containers

Tags: mysql, docker, symfony, doctrine-orm, mariadb

I have set up a dev environment with Symfony and MariaDB through docker.

I've taken the bitman/symfony image there :

```
 https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/symfony
```

This is my **docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '2'

services:
  myapp:
    image: 'bitnami/symfony:1'
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
    environment:
      - SYMFONY_PROJECT_NAME=backend
      - MARIADB_PORT_NUMBER=3306
      - MARIADB_USER=root
    container_name: symfony_container
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
  mariadb:
    image: 'bitnami/mariadb:10.3'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
  environment:
    - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    - MARIADB_USER=root
  container_name: mariadb_container
```

Important line in **.env file** :

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:@localhost:3306/
```

My **doctrine.yaml** file:

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
      url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
      server_version: '5.7'
  orm:
      auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
      naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
      auto_mapping: true
      mappings:
          App:
              is_bundle: false
              type: annotation
              dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
              prefix: 'App\Entity'
              alias: App
```

Now if I run **docker-compose up**, both containers start and I can access Symfony.

BUT if I try to create an entity with :

```
php bin/console make:entity
```

I get the four following errors :

```
An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution 

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution  

PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

The strange thing is that I can access MariaDB database through dbeaver without trouble. It seems as if the Symfony container did not manage to find the MariaDB container.

I'll precise that I use symfony version 5.0.4

If anyone knows where those errors come from I'll be grateful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:@**localhost**:3306/

In the context of docker, `localhost` is the current running container. Since this is used from your symfony container, it will try to find the db there.

From your `docker-compose.yml` file, your db service is named `mariadb` and will be resolved as such from the containers participating in your application default network:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:@mariadb:3306/
```

Note: I suspect you may have other problems to solve related to your db users settings once the connection is fixed. If this is the case, carefully review the [your db image configuration documentation](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mariadb#configuration).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Zeitounator solution, but in my host, if I launch
`php bin/console doctrine:migration:migrate`
it returns an error :
`could not translate host name "mariadb" to address: Name or service not known`
I solved by add in my **/etc/hosts** :
`127.0.0.1    mariadb`
and it works on host and in container

Comment: If you develop using docker(-compose) you should launch that command inside your php container. Doing it from your docker controller can lead to unexpected results if you have different versions or configuration of php => `docker-compose exec myapp php bin/console doctrine:migration:migrate`. And in this case the `mariadb` container will be known.